# Enzyme won't detect components from React Native Elements

Tags: javascript, react-native, enzyme, react-native-elements

I am testing my component using Jest and Enzyme which has `Input` component from React Native Elements but I am getting error

```
Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead
```

Here is my code:

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import TransactionDetails from '../../app/BankingFeatures/components/transactionDetails';

const userProfile = {
    data: {
        user_profile: {
            name: 'ashwith',
            payment_status_id: '1234556'
        }
    }
};

const state = {
    name: 'ashwith',
    amount: null,
    transaction_id: null,
    transaction_date: '2019/06/18',
    transaction_type: null,
    name_status: undefined,
    amount_status: undefined,
    transaction_id_status: undefined,
    transaction_date_status: undefined,
    transaction_type_status: undefined,
};

describe('Transaction Test', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TransactionDetails
        userProfile={userProfile}
    />);
    const input = wrapper.find('Input').at(0);
    input.simulate('changeText', 'eths');
});
```

transactionDetails.js

```
import moment from 'moment';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker';
import Spinner from 'react-native-loading-spinner-overlay';
import { Icon, Input, Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import { 
    View, 
    Text, 
    ScrollView, 
    Platform, 
    KeyboardAvoidingView, 
} from 'react-native';


import { Colors } from '../../Metrics';
import { styles } from '../styles/transactionDetails';
import MainContainer from '../../Utilities/mainContainer';
import * as Errmsg from '../../../config/Contents/errMessages';
import * as Placeholdermsg from '../../../config/Contents/placeHolders';

class TransactionDetails extends Component {

    // State
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const { userProfile } = this.props;
        const userData = userProfile && userProfile.data && userProfile.data.user_profile;
        const dateNow = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
        this.state = {
            name: userData ? userData.name : null,
            amount: null,
            transaction_id: null,
            transaction_date: dateNow,
            transaction_type: null,
            name_status: undefined,
            amount_status: undefined,
            transaction_id_status: undefined,
            transaction_date_status: undefined,
            transaction_type_status: undefined,
        };
    }

    getState = () => this.state;

    change = (transaction_id, amount) => this.setState({ transaction_id, amount });

    // Validating Transaction
    async nameValidation() {
        const { name } = this.state;
        const name_status = name ? undefined : Errmsg.name;

        if (name_status === undefined) {
            // this.tranIdInput.focus();
        } else {
            await this.setState({
                name_status
            });
        }
    }


    // Validating Transaction Date
    async transactionDateValidation() {
        const { transaction_date } = this.state;
        const transaction_date_status = await transaction_date ? undefined : 'Transaction date required';

        if (transaction_date_status === undefined) {
            this.tranIdInput.focus();
        } else {
            await this.setState({
                transaction_date_status
            });
        }
    }

    // Validating Transaction ID
    async transIdValidation() {
        const { transaction_id } = this.state;

        const transaction_id_status = transaction_id ? undefined : 'Transaction id required';

        if (transaction_id_status === undefined) {
            // this.transTypenput.focus();
        } else {
            await this.setState({
                transaction_id_status
            });
        }
    }

    // Validating Transaction Type
    async transTypeValidation() {
        const { transaction_type } = this.state;

        const transaction_type_status = transaction_type ? undefined : 'Transaction type required';

        if (transaction_type_status === undefined) {
            this.amountInput.focus();
        } else {
            await this.setState({
                transaction_type_status
            });
        }
    }

    // Validating Amount
    async amountValidation() {
        const { amount } = this.state;

        const amount_status = !isNaN(amount) ? amount && amount.length >= 5 ? undefined : 'min you can add 10000' : 'Amount required';

        if (amount_status === undefined) {
            // this.btnPress();
        } else {
            await this.setState({
                amount_status
            });
        }
    }

    // Submitting Transaction details
    btnPress() {
        const { actions } = this.props;
        const {
            name,
            amount,
            transaction_id,
            transaction_date,
            transaction_type,
        } = this.state;

        actions.addBankTransactionDetails({
            name,
            amount,
            transaction_id,
            transaction_date,
            transaction_type,
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {
            name_status,
            amount_status,
            transaction_id_status,
            transaction_date_status,
            transaction_type_status,
        } = this.state;
        const { addBankTransactionDetails } = this.props;

        return (
            <MainContainer style={styles.container}>
                <Spinner 
                    cancelable
                    visible={addBankTransactionDetails && addBankTransactionDetails.isLoading} 
                    textContent={'Loading...'} 
                />
                <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' && 'height'}>
                <ScrollView
                    bounces={false}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                >
                <View style={styles.formContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>Add Transaction Details</Text>
                    <Input
                        placeholder={Placeholdermsg.name}
                        ref={this.nameInput}
                        leftIcon={
                            <Icon
                                name='user'
                                size={24}
                                color={Colors.grey}
                                type='font-awesome'
                            />
                        }
                        autoFocus
                        value={this.state.name}
                        autoCapitalize='characters'
                        returnKeyType='next'
                        onSubmitEditing={() => { this.nameValidation(); }}
                        onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({ name, name_status: undefined })}
                        inputStyle={styles.textinput}
                        containerStyle={styles.textFeildContainer}
                        inputContainerStyle={styles.textFeild}
                        errorMessage={(name_status) || null}
                    />
                    <DatePicker
                        style={styles.dateContainer}
                        date={this.state.transaction_date}
                        mode="date"
                        placeholder="Select transaction date"
                        format="YYYY/MM/DD"
                        minDate="2019-01-01"
                        confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                        cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                        iconComponent={
                            <Icon
                                name="calendar"
                                type="entypo"
                                size={24}
                                color={Colors.grey}
                                containerStyle={{
                                    position: 'absolute',
                                    left: 10,
                                    top: 8,
                                    marginLeft: 0
                                }}
                            />
                        }
                        customStyles={{
                            dateIcon: {
                                position: 'absolute',
                                left: 0,
                                top: 4,
                                marginLeft: 0
                            },
                            dateInput: {
                                height: 50,
                                marginLeft: 50,
                                borderWidth: 0,
                                alignItems: 'flex-start',
                            }
                        }}
                        onCloseModal={() => this.transactionDateValidation()}
                        onDateChange={async (transaction_date) => { this.setState({ transaction_date, transaction_date_status: undefined }, () => { console.log(transaction_date); }); this.transactionDateValidation(); }}
                    />
                    {
                        (transaction_date_status !== undefined) &&
                        <View style={styles.errorContainer}>
                            <Text style={styles.errText}>{transaction_date_status}</Text>
                        </View>
                    }
                    <Input
                        ref={(input) => { this.tranIdInput = input; }}
                        placeholder='Enter transaction id'
                        leftIcon={
                            <Icon
                                name='key'
                                size={24}
                                color={Colors.grey}
                                type='entypo'
                            />
                        }
                        autoCapitalize='characters'
                        returnKeyType='next'
                        onSubmitEditing={() => { this.transIdValidation(); }}
                        onChangeText={(transaction_id) => this.setState({ transaction_id, transaction_id_status: undefined })}
                        inputStyle={styles.textinput}
                        containerStyle={styles.textFeildContainer}
                        inputContainerStyle={styles.textFeild}
                        errorMessage={(transaction_id_status) || null}
                    />
                    <Input
                        ref={(input) => { this.transTypenput = input; }}
                        placeholder='Enter transaction type'
                        leftIcon={
                            <Icon
                                name='bank'
                                size={20}
                                color={Colors.grey}
                                type='font-awesome'
                            />
                        }
                        autoCapitalize='characters'
                        returnKeyType='next'
                        onSubmitEditing={() => { this.transTypeValidation(); }}
                        onChangeText={(transaction_type) => this.setState({ transaction_type, transaction_type_status: undefined })}
                        inputStyle={styles.textinput}
                        containerStyle={styles.textFeildContainer}
                        inputContainerStyle={styles.textFeild}
                        errorMessage={(transaction_type_status) || null}
                    />
                    <Input
                        ref={(input) => { this.amountInput = input; }}
                        placeholder='Enter Amount'
                        leftIcon={
                            <Icon
                                name='rupee'
                                size={24}
                                color={Colors.grey}
                                type='font-awesome'
                            />
                        }
                        keyboardType='numeric'
                        returnKeyType='done'
                        onSubmitEditing={() => { this.amountValidation(); }}
                        onChangeText={(amount) => this.setState({ amount, amount_status: undefined })}
                        inputStyle={styles.textinput}
                        containerStyle={styles.textFeildContainer}
                        inputContainerStyle={styles.textFeild}
                        errorMessage={(amount_status) || null}
                    />
                </View>
                </ScrollView>
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                <View style={styles.bottomContainer}>
                    <Button
                        title="Submit"
                        buttonStyle={styles.Button}
                        onPress={() => this.btnPress()}
                        containerStyle={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }}
                    />
                </View>
            </MainContainer>
        );
    }
}

export default TransactionDetails;
```

debug

```
<MainContainer style={{...}}>
      <Spinner cancelable={true} visible={false} textContent="Loading..." animation="none" color="white" size="large" overlayColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)" />
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{...}} behavior="height" enabled={true} keyboardVerticalOffset={0}>
        <ScrollViewMock bounces={false} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <View style={{...}}>
            <Text style={{...}}>
              Add Transaction Details
            </Text>
            <ForwardRef(Themed.Input) placeholder="Enter name" leftIcon={{...}} autoFocus={true} value="ashwith" autoCapitalize="characters" returnKeyType="next" onSubmitEditing={[Function: onSubmitEditing]} onChangeText={[Function: onChangeText]} inputStyle={{...}} containerStyle={{...}} inputContainerStyle={{...}} errorMessage={{...}} />
            <DatePicker style={{...}} date="2019/06/24" mode="date" placeholder="Select transaction date" format="YYYY/MM/DD" minDate="2019-01-01" confirmBtnText="Confirm" cancelBtnText="Cancel" iconComponent={{...}} customStyles={{...}} onCloseModal={[Function: onCloseModal]} onDateChange={[Function: _callee]} androidMode="default" height={259} duration={300} iconSource={{...}} showIcon={true} disabled={false} allowFontScaling={true} hideText={false} TouchableComponent={[Function]} modalOnResponderTerminationRequest={[Function: modalOnResponderTerminationRequest]} />
            <ForwardRef(Themed.Input) placeholder="Enter transaction id" leftIcon={{...}} autoCapitalize="characters" returnKeyType="next" onSubmitEditing={[Function: onSubmitEditing]} onChangeText={[Function: onChangeText]} inputStyle={{...}} containerStyle={{...}} inputContainerStyle={{...}} errorMessage={{...}} />
            <ForwardRef(Themed.Input) placeholder="Enter transaction type" leftIcon={{...}} autoCapitalize="characters" returnKeyType="next" onSubmitEditing={[Function: onSubmitEditing]} onChangeText={[Function: onChangeText]} inputStyle={{...}} containerStyle={{...}} inputContainerStyle={{...}} errorMessage={{...}} />
            <ForwardRef(Themed.Input) placeholder="Enter Amount" leftIcon={{...}} keyboardType="numeric" returnKeyType="done" onSubmitEditing={[Function: onSubmitEditing]} onChangeText={[Function: onChangeText]} inputStyle={{...}} containerStyle={{...}} inputContainerStyle={{...}} errorMessage={{...}} />
          </View>
        </ScrollViewMock>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      <View style={{...}}>
        <ForwardRef(Themed.Button) title="Submit" buttonStyle={{...}} onPress={[Function: onPress]} containerStyle={{...}} />
      </View>
    </MainContainer>
```

Comment: Can you post your `TransactionDetails` component ?

Comment: Can you post the output of `wrapper.debug()`?

Comment: I suspect the `ScrollView` being the problem: the serializer of the wrapper may mock ScrollView, which not really render the children so there is no `Input` . As @MarcelKalveram suggested, a debug would help to confirm that. If it's confirmed, try to refactor this big component with a presentational component for all code under the <ScrollView>. Then test this behavior.

Comment: if i use Input from react-native ill test will be successfull